# Deleting data by date where date is in text format YYYY/MM

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to run a delete query in VBA to delete records containing a billing month that's greater than a precalculated current month. The source data from another system has the dates in text format, shown as (YYYY/MM).

Here's the statement:

```
mySQL = "DELETE * FROM [tblBillingData]" _
& "WHERE (((tblBillingData.[Billing Month]) > PreCalcCurrentMonth));"

DoCmd.RunSQL mySQL
```

All variables are declared properly and I can see the PreCalcCurrentMonth when I step through the code, but when it runs the SQL statement, I'm presented with an Enter Parameter input box for the PreCalcCurrentMonth variable.

Comment: Is the variable declared in the VBA? If so, shouldn't you be using a prepared statement?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that `PreCalcCurrentMonth` is a Date variable, try something like this:

```
mySQL = "DELETE * FROM [tblBillingData]" & _
   "WHERE (((tblBillingData.[Billing Month]) > " & _
    Format(PreCalcCurrentMonth,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
    "));"

 DoCmd.RunSQL mySQL
```

`Format(PreCalcCurrentMonth,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")` ensures that your date is converted to a string in US date format #mm/dd/yyyy#, whatever your regional settings. # is the date separator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mySQL = "DELETE * FROM [tblBillingData]" _
& "WHERE (((tblBillingData.[Billing Month]) > #" & PreCalcCurrentMonth & "#));"
```

First, you need to refer to your variable as a variable outside the string, otherwise, Access VBA thinks its a string.

Second, you need to surround date paramters with the `#` sign.

Comment: Just a follow-up on this. I ran it with the # marks and it deleted everything. Fortunately it was just a test table and when I re-ran everything, but removed the # sign, it seemed to work as desired.  Again, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @edsac64 Maybe because of the way your date is formatted, it doesn't need the #. Anyway, glad you got your answer.